# How to implement non-blocking logging in Web API 2 action filters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I have an `ActionFilterAttribute` similar to this.

```
public override async Task OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Task.Delay(3*1000);
}
```

In the place of `Task.Delay` let's say I have an async logging service call which has some latency.

My issue is that I haven't found any way yet to make the logging not to block the request-response process. So this `Task.Delay` will block the response to flush out. I'd like to avoid this to keep a good user experience regarding response times.

What is the proper approach of doing this?

Comment: If you don't want to wait, don't `await`. If you want to ensure everything is logged though, don't use a logging service with latency. Worst case, create your own "client library" that logs messages to a queue and sends them to the slow service. That's how Application Insights works btw. Or you can do what [Logary](https://github.com/logary/logary#why-do-you-depend-on-hopac) does and target eg RabbitMQ

Answer (score 0):

Fire it of using a new task to keep it on a separate thread.

```
Task.Run(() => logger.Debug("This is a log entry"));
```

Most logging frameworks already have Async-methods you could use which does this.  If they are properly implemented you won't be adding any extra delay. Remember that this will log using fire and forget (no feedback) and you won't be able to control the *order* of log events as they will not be written sequentially.

However, the preferred way of doing this is to write an asynchronous log appender rather than doing it in some OWIN middleware that developer might easily miss.

Comment: That's what the OP already does. The only difference is there's no `await`